# how to activate loaddata() from another class

Tags: java, android

i have this code in the Main extends Activity

```
    public void loaddata()
    {
        Toast.makeText(Main.this, ("Working"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

i use this in the second extends Activity

```
    public void turnon() 
    {
        Main dp = new Main();
        dp.loaddata();
    }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);

    okbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okbutton);

    okbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    { 
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
              turnon();
        }
    });
}
```

but it give force close 
any idea

Comment: welcome to stackOverFlow!!! http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: im trying to load data from the second class to the main while the Main is in background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create Public class and then put that code inside then access it.

Ex:-

```
public class GLobal{

public static void loaddata(Activity act)
    {
        Toast.makeText(act, "Working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

And call like this...

```
Global.loaddata(this);
```